# About eigenvalues and complex matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $A$ is a square complex matrix with $n$ rows, prove that the constant term of the characteristic polynomial is equal to $(-1)^ndet(A)$ and that the coefficient of degree $n-1$ is equal to $-Tr(A)$

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know about Schur's decomposition? (It states that any matrix is similar to an upper triangular matrix).

Comment: Constant term it is. I´ll change it in a bit, thanks. No, I didn´t know, I´m interested in learning, of course, but I also want to know a way to do it with what I already know of eigenspaces. I mean, I am suppossed to be able to solve it. I just don´t know where to begin.

Comment: you actually want to prove that trace is sum of eigenvalues and  determinant is product of eigen values.. right?

Comment: Yes that´s right. I´m only missing the part of the trace...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $\det(zI_n-A)=(z-\lambda _1)\cdot \ldots \cdot(z-\lambda _n)$, for certain scalars $\lambda _1, \ldots ,\lambda _n$.

You'd like to show that $\det(A)=\lambda _1\cdot\ldots \cdot\lambda _n$.

**Hint$_\bf1$:** What can you pick to replace $z$ to help you with this?

---

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n}\\ a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \cdots & a_{nn}\end{bmatrix}$.

**Hint$_\bf 2$:** Prove on the one hand that $$\det(zI_n-A)=z^n+b_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\ldots+b_1z+b_0,$$ for certain $b_{n-1}, \ldots ,b_0\in \mathbb C$, where $b_{n-1}=a_{11}+\ldots +a_{nn}$ and on the other hand that
$$(z-\lambda _1)\cdot \ldots \cdot(z-\lambda _n)=z^n+(\lambda_1+\ldots +\lambda _n)z^{n-1}+\ldots +(\lambda _1\cdot \ldots \cdot\lambda _n).$$

(Use [Vieta's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas)).

Comment: Thank you! One thing though... I did all that, but I´m missing one thing, and it´s the proof that the trace is the sum of eigenvalues... any idea of how should I start to prove that?

Comment: @LunaSage Do you require further help?

Comment: I think I don't... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hint (for that $\det$-thing): for any polynomial $f$ of degree $n$ it's additive constant equals $f(0)$. Now plug in $\lambda=0$ in $\det(A-\lambda I)$.