# Proof that the characteristic polynomial of a $2 \times 2$ matrix is $x^2 - \text{tr}(A) x + \det (A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, determinant, trace

Let $$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12}\\
a_{21} & a_{22}\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Let $C_{A}(x) := \det(xI-A)$ be the characteristic polynomial of A. Show that $$C_{A}(x)=x^2-\text{tr}(A)x+\det(A).$$

I know that $\text{tr}(A)=a_{11}+a_{22}$ and $\det(A)=a_{11}a_{22}-a_{21}a_{12}$. Plugging this into the above equation I get $$C_{A}(x)=x^2-(a_{11}+a_{22})x+a_{11}a_{22}-a_{21}a_{12}.$$

I'm not sure how to get past this. As you can tell, I'm not too good at proofs. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Calculate $\det(xI-A)$ and check that you get the same thing.

Comment: Generalizations: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/599502 and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/730071

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're there.  It's like you've reached the front door without recognizing it.  Just take the equation you've derived for the characteristic polynomial

$C_A(x) = \det(x I - A) = x^2 - (a_{11} + a_{22})x + a_{11}a_{22} - a_{21}a_{12}, \tag{1}$

plug in your formulas for trace and determinant:

$tr(A) = a_{11} + a_{22}, \; \; \det(A) = a_{11}a_{22} - a_{21}a_{12}, \tag{2}$

and *voila!*, you obtain

$C_A(x) = X^2 - tr(A) + \det (A); \tag{3}$

behold!  As if Aladdin had said the magic word, the front door swings open, and you're in (to the room of the right answer)!

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as ever,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 3):

So far so good.

On the other hand, computing $C_A(x)$ directly using the definition gives
$$
C_A(x)
= \det(x I - A)
= \det\begin{pmatrix}x - a_{11} & -a_{12} \\ -a_{21} & x - a_{22}\end{pmatrix}
= (x - a_{11})(x - a_{22}) - (-a_{12})(-a_{21}) .
$$
All that remains is to show that this agrees with the expression you already produced.